# Strip Outer Element Twice when uploading XML File to Snowflake

Tags: python, xml, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, azure-data-factory

I have some XML data I am trying to load into Snowflake that is structured basically like so:

```
<Data>
    <Details About the Data>
    </Details About the Data>
    <Employees>
        <Employee> (there are thousands of these with many properties)
        </Employee>
    </Employees>
</Data>
```

When trying to upload this data to Snowflake, I am finding that unless I basically manually delete the outermost element, it will give me an error due to row size limitations, since it is trying to put all the information about 'Employees' into a single row.

This is even while having the 'strip outer element' property selected (it gets rid of 'data', but not 'employees').

What I am trying to do is essentially perform the 'strip outer element' process twice, but I have not found any simple or straightforward ways to do this in Snowflake.

I am sure I could do something like this in Python, but we are trying to avoid that if possible. I would also be open to performing this transformation in Azure Data Factory if it is not possible in Snowflake.

Any advice on this would be appreciated.

Comment: Start by uploading a **VALID** XML doc. Explain what is the manipulation you need to do with it. Show the result of the manipulation as another **VALID** xml.

Answer (score 1):

Add a data flow activity and add the XML source to your data flow. Next, add a Derived Column.

This is where you can manipulate data structures like the Data structure you have here. For the column name, select the top-level element, which is Data in your case. You're going to redefine it here without one of the elements you wish to remove. Inside the expression builder, find the Data structure under Expression Values.

In my example, my hierarchy is called "shiporder". Click the curly braces icon {}. You should now have the full structure described in your expression builder. Take out whichever element you wish to remove and then save & close.

[image]